# no consigo centrar el texto en un div materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

tengo la siguiente etiqueta html, tengo el boton bien posicionado, con el tamaño y colores que quiero, pero no consigo usar en ningun sitio correctamente el display flex para que el texto salga centrado

```css
.filaXpac{
  height: 18%;  position: relative;
margin-left: 5% !important;  width: 90%;
}
.colXsalirpac{
    position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.alto100{
  height: 100% !important;
}
.rowsalir{
      width: 130px;
    height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #f5f5f5 ;
        background-color: #959f6b;
        border-radius: 5px;
}
.colorsalir{
 color: #f5f5f5 ; 
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 font-weight: 400;
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row filaXpac  ">
              <div class="col s12 colXsalirpac alto100 ">

                <div id="botonXsalirR" class="row rowsalir">
                  <div id="PsalR"  class="col s12 alto100 colorsalir">salir de aqui mismo
                
              </div>
                </div>
               
              </div>
             </div>
```

el tema es que no consigo que se me centre el texto... estoy usando la capa de materialize

Comment: Has probado con text-align?

Comment: center-align poniendo eso en la ultima etiqueta del html me funciona, pero queria saber por que no me funcionaba por css, Gracias!!

Comment: Realmente si está centrando el contenido pero no se ve centrado porque el texto en si no tiene alineación. Si cambias el tamaño de '.rowsalir' y lo haces más grande verás que el contenido si que está centrado. Con 'text-align: center;' en '.colorSalir' centrará el texto dentro del espacio que tiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no tienes que usar flex, sólo tienes que usar la propiedad `text-align:center;` y con eso solucionas todo. Tienes que agregar la propiedad en la clase `.colXsalirpac`. Te quedaría así el código:

```
.colXsalirpac{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Saludos y espero que funcione.